# The linebreak option doesn’t work well in Vim when s, S or c + <cr> are used

Tags: vim

I’ve noticed a weird behaviour of (g)Vim: say I have a window with a line longer than its width and I’ve `set wrap linebreak cursorline`, if I hit <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>`motion` or <kbd>cc</kbd> (but not <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>) on another line and then hit <kbd>↵</kbd>, lines on this window are for some mysterious cause no longer wrapped at word boundaries (it looks as if I’ve `set wrap nolinebreak`). If I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> it returns to normal display.

This should obviously not occur. Is it a bug in Vim or something I did wrong? It occurs when invoking Vim *tabula rasa* (`vim --noplugins -u NONE` or `gvim --noplugins -u NONE`) as well. My machine is Arch Linux, and the Vim version I use is 7.4.537. I’ve tested it on another Arch Linux machine I have and it behaves the same, but when I `ssh`ed my DreamHost account, on which Vim 7.3.429 is installed, it behaves as it should.

Note: it doesn’t occur without `cursorline` on another line, so I guess it’s connected somehow, but I’m not really sure how. It occurs anyway if edit using <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> on the same long line (than it affects only this line).

Can you confirm or disconfirm this erroneous behaviour occurs on your machine? How can one fix this?

(If it isn’t only me and it *is* a bug, I’ll send a bug report).

Thank you very much! ☺

Comment: Confirmed for Vim 7.4.540 on Ubuntu. This does not reproduce for Vim 7.4.52 (which is installed by `apt`) on the same machine.  +1 for catching this.

Comment: So it’s not only me; good to know, thanks. For the time being, I use the `map` command to work around this bug: `map s xi`, `map cc ddO` and `map S cc`. It’s not perfect, but it’s better than the current situation. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Was a bug ever submitted, or was a solution found? I'm having the same issue, and it's really starting to annoy me. I hadn't considered that it might be a recently-introduced issue.

Comment: @Z1MM32M4N: Not yet. I’m in the final stages of writing my MA thesis, so I don’t have much time nowadays. Once it’s submitted, I’ll write a bug report. If you want to do it yourself more quickly, tell me so I will not send a redundant bug report.

Comment: @Yosh The last unaffected version available at snapshots.debian.org is `7.4.430-1`. `deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140907/ jessie main` (`sid` should be too).

Comment: @Z1MM32M4N As I’ve been told in correspondent [Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=774492), a week ago this very question from SO was forwarded to [to the vim-dev](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/48703), where it was pointed out than that is [a bit older issue](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/48283/focus=48307) and patch is already [written](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/48064/focus=48174).

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Thank you for the information. It is fairly detailed, I think you should post that as an answer and accept yourself :). (Or perhaps wait until the patch is merged?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, this was indeed a bug, and was patched in 7.4 with [patch #576](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.576).